# Multiple call to function which has recursive asynchronous calculation

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, recursion, jquery-deferred

I have ordered list on UI and each li has event handler and call as shown below in the code.

Here I want the array of allchildnodes as an output from my getAllOrgChildrenNodes() by just passing the current node id and the total count of the children which exist inside it.
eg.

- firstli (total7)

  - first11

    - first 111

      - first 1111
    - first 112

      - first 1121
      - first 1122
  - first12
- secondli(total4)

  ```
  $(document).on("click", ".li", function (e) {
  //statement x
  //statement y
  //statement z
  var Nodeid=$(this).data("id");//id of the .li
  var totalchildren=$(this).data("totalchildren");
      $.when(getAllOrgChildrenNodes(NodeID,totalchildren,mycount)).done(function (AllChildNodes) {
              mycount=0;
              //Do calculation here for 
              //with AllChildNodes

      });
  });

  /* getAllOrgChildrenNodes */
  var AllChildNodes = []; // clear AllChildNodes in the calling function
  var mycount = 0;
  function getAllOrgChildrenNodes(NodeID, totalcount, deferred) {
      if (!deferred) {
          deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
      }
      var IParentID= NodeID;

      //consider the below as any ajax call which gives list of array back
      //from above example firstli will give first11 and first 12 as o/p
      //in next recursion first11 will be parent and o/p will be first111 and first112
      db_mob_audit.values('OrgChildrenNodeInfo', IParentID).done(function (ListOfNodes) {
          if (ListOfNodes.length > 0) {
              for (i = 0; i < ListOfNodes.length; i++) {
                  var CurrentNode = ListOfNodes[i];
                  AllChildNodes.push(CurrentNode);
                  getAllOrgChildrenNodes(CurrentNode.INodeID, totalcount, deferred);
              }
          }
          mycount = mycount + ListOfNodes.length;
          if (mycount == totalcount) {
              mycount = 0;
              deferred.resolve(AllChildNodes);
          }
      });
      return deferred.promise();
  }
  ```

Now, the problem is like I was using mycount and Allchildnodes as global variable, I think because of that if the user clicks on secondli during firstli execution is going on, then the variables gets overwritten.

Comment: Should be able to prove that by putting everything inside the click handler to try wrapping in closure

Comment: If possible , can post `html` ?

Comment: @charlietfl I tried that but then mycount and Allchild are no longer global variables and they loose their context inside the  db_mob_audit.values('OrgChildrenNodeInfo', IParentID).done({    ///lost scope  });  here.

Comment: even when the getAllOrgChildrenNodes() declaration is inside clcik handler?